# Qt Android output apk generated in ~/android-build\build\outputs\apk\debug

Tags: android, qt, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

**Problem**: I want to use Android build system (gradle version 3) with Qt project, but this version of gradle (compared to old version 2) would change location of generated output `apk` file to be under `$buildDir/outputs/apk/debug` instead of `$buildDir/outputs/apk` (added `debug` folder), but when Qt Android kit tries to install app to Android device it only looks in old location, and fails to locate the apk file. I checked with Android Studio and its same which indicates gradle 3 is working normal

old location: `$build_folder/android-build\build\outputs\apk\my.apk` 
New location: `$build_folder/android-build\build\outputs\apk\debug\my.apk`

**Error (Compile)**:

> adb: error: cannot stat
>   'D:/Qt/FireBase/build-client01-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_11_0_for_Android_armv73-Release/android-build//build/outputs/apk/android-build-debug.apk':
>   No such file or directory

This problem occurs only when I make changes to default `build.gradle` generated by Qt to set gradle to version 3, the default generated file have `classpath` set to old version `2.3.3`,

old: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'` 
new : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0`

There are other changes I made, that also require change in `gradle-wrapper.properties`, here are updated files:

> build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1' // google-services plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        //google() // Google's Maven repository
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
  // ...


    //libfirebase_auth.a
    //libfirebase_app.a
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Feb 20 10:43:22 EST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this on my build.gradle :

```
android {
...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "../" + outputFileName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works and indeed better, but still when I run it, the `debug` folder is created (thats ok) but still the file `output.json` is left in `debug` folder. I feel there is still a missing ring from Qt side as it searches for `apk` file in `apk` folder

Comment: what is output.json? I don't have it on my project

Comment: I am not familair with it, It just started appearing along my gradle version change! its a single line `[{"outputType":{"type":"APK"},"apkInfo":{"type":"MAIN","splits":[],"versionCode":1,"versionName":"1.0","enabled":true,"outputFile":"../android-build-debug.apk","fullName":"debug","baseName":"debug"},"path":"..\\android-build-debug.apk","properties":{}}]`

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know where and how to instruct Qt to look into new output structure, but as a workaround for now , I added configuration to `build.gradle` to make a copy of the generated `apk` back to `~/apk` where Qt looks for!

```
// make a copy of APK from "$buildDir/outputs/apk/debug" back to "$buildDir/outputs/apk"
def archiveBuildTypes = ["release", "debug"];
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all { output ->
        if (variant.buildType.name in archiveBuildTypes) {
            def taskSuffix = variant.name.capitalize()
            def assembleTaskName = "assemble${taskSuffix}"
            if (tasks.findByName(assembleTaskName)) {
                def copyAPKFolderTask = tasks.create(name: "archive${taskSuffix}", type: org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy) {
                    description "copy APK to old folder"
                    def sourceFolder = "$buildDir/outputs/apk/$output.baseName"
                    def destinationFolder = "$buildDir/outputs/apk"
                    print "Copy apk from: $sourceFolder into $destinationFolder\n"
                    from(sourceFolder)
                    into destinationFolder
                    eachFile { file ->
                        file.path = file.name // so we have a "flat" copy
                    }
                    includeEmptyDirs = false
                }
                tasks[assembleTaskName].finalizedBy = [copyAPKFolderTask]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
`gradle 3.1.x` and higher require at least `androidBuildToolsVersion 27`, while Qt currently supports no higher than `androidBuildToolsVersion 26`, So practically may be its safer to fall back to  `gradle 3.0.x` which supports build tools 26 
It's also even possible to fall back to `gradle 2.3.3` (use `compile` instead of `implementation` for `FireBase` and any required modules:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
...
```